# Rails form, iterating over a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, simple-form

I'm trying to iterate over a collection in a form, where I would like to ask the user to fill in a quantity for each individual extra_guest.

My current form indeed shows the collection as intended, but does not pass the `extra_guest_id` to `reservation_extra_guest`.

models

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reservation_extra_guests, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :extra_guests, through: :reservation_extra_guests
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :reservation_extra_guests
end

class ReservationExtraGuest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :extra_guest
  belongs_to :reservation
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :extra_guest
end

class ExtraGuest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :age_table
  has_many :reservation_extra_guests
  has_many :reservations, through: :reservation_extra_guests
end
```

controller

```
def new_second_part
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
    @guests = []
    @reservation.room.room_category.extra_guests.each do |guest|
      res_guest = @reservation.reservation_extra_guests.build
      res_guest[:extra_guest_id] = guest.id
      @guests << res_guest
    end
end
```

form

```
<%= simple_form_for [@hotel, @reservation] do |f|%>

<%= f.simple_fields_for :reservation_extra_guests do |g| %>
  <p><%= g.object.extra_guest.age_table.name %>
  <%= g.input :extra_guest_quantity, label: false, collection: 1..20 %></p>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

params sent

```
"reservation"=>{"reservation_extra_guests_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"extra_guest_quantity"=>"3"}, "1"=>{"extra_guest_quantity"=>"4"}}
```

Comment: What are your associations? try with `simple_fields_for :reservation_extra_guests` in plural (and remove the `@guests.each` block and use `c.object` to get the current guest of the iteration)

Comment: Thank you, that indeed passed the extra_guest_quantity_params. Up to the next bug, as the  ```extra_guest_id``` I thought I passed in the ```new_second_part``` action is not passed. ```"reservation"=>{"reservation_extra_guests_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"extra_guest_quantity"=>"3"}, "1"=>{"extra_guest_quantity"=>"4"}}```.

Comment: You have to add a hidden field with the extra_guest_id: `g.input :extra_guest_id, as: :hidden`

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked.